# Kenmore washer won't agitate or spin

Tags: appliances

I have a Kenmore washing machine model 110.29802890 that will not spin or agitate.  It fills and drains,but on spin or wash cycle barrel does not move, and makes a kind of grinding noise.  Please help.

Comment: Sounds like either the agitator motor or transmission is kaput.

Comment: Kaput, https://www.wordnik.com/words/kaput  OR Kaput, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaput

Comment: Did you ever find out what was wrong with this washing machine?  This sounds like a bad clutch on the transmission shaft or a bad transmission.  Grinding wouldn't be the motor since it is turning to create the noise.  Also, the drain pump works too since it is attached to the motor.

Answer (score 0):

It is helpful that you shared the model number. A quick search provided your answers below.

http://www.repairclinic.com/RepairHelp/Washing-Machine-Repair/11-6-187001-/Kenmore-Washing-Machine-11029802890-Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

If it won't agitate or spin and you couldn't hear a grinding noise i'd say check for faulty lid switch first.but as you can hear a grinding noise the motor is turning but the motor coupling that joins the motor to the transmission sounds broken and needs replacing.very rarely does a transmission wear out or stop working so always check other parts first.good luck with the repair
PS if the transmission is spinning but won't agitate or spin then the motor coupler is working and the drive block and bell could be worn out.